# Angular service not updating on model change

Tags: service, angularjs

In may app I have a service which holds my tasks:

```
app.factory('Tasks', function () {
    var tasks = [];
    return {
        getAll: function () { return tasks; },
        addOne: function (task) { tasks.push(task); },
        openBy: function(owner) {
            return _.where(tasks, {owner: owner, status: 'open'});
        },
        doneBy: function(owner) {
            return _.where(tasks, {owner: owner, status: 'closed'});
        },
    };
});
```

I then show, per owner, either their open tasks or closed tasks.

The problem is that when I update the tasks by using `Tasks.addOne(task);` the views that use `Tasks.openBy(owner)` don't get updated. The ones that use `Tasks.getAll()` do.

Is this because I am returning a new array? If so is there a way of telling the controller to update what it has? Or am I just doing this entirely wrong in the first place and is there a better way to do it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Matthew

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you return a new array on `openBy(owner)`, which is not being changed/updated afterwards. One solution is to use always `getAll()` and then filter by user/status directly on the the view (i.e. `task in tasks | filter:{owner: owner, status: 'open'}`).

Comment: I have tried that but I need them to be distinct models in the view because I am updating keys from indexes on re-arrange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is to call the openBy function in the controller (or directive) rather than in the view and wrap it into a $scope.$watch invocation. As an example:

```
// Controller body
app.controller('TasksCtrl', function($scope, Tasks) {
  $scope.allTasks = Tasks.getAll();
  $scope.$watch('allTasks', function() {
    // Assume owner is the user and it's initialised somewhere above
    $scope.ownedTasks = tasks.openBy(owner);
  }, true);
});
```

This should work, even though I think that it should be possible to do something more elegant maybe!

Comment: All right, I have added true as the third argument to $watch and it seems to be working now. Thanks.